# How to access virtual hostname xampp in local network (LAN)

Tags: apache, xampp

I just want to ask a simple question.

**Here is the explanation**:

I've set virtual host name and it was work perfectly. When i access from another computer using the computer server ip address like for example :

```
http://192.168.0.100:8088/myfolder
```

It still work (I change the port to 8088 because port 80 clash with Skype)

I have 1 problem, when I access the virtual name on different computer (still in same lan) it will not work and it will redirect me to open dns bla bla bla (because the page was not found)

Here is my configuration :

I've added the text below hosts file in System32

> - 127.0.0.1      debate.service
> - 192.168.0.100      your.service (Its dynamic ip from router to my server)

debate.service just for localhost like usual

your.service for another computer who was in the same lan (I want to access this web server on others computer)

I use wireless router to connect to the LAN network and use dynamic IP, but I know it will change dynamically (I just want to test the virtual host name)

Here is my http-vhosts.conf :

```
NameVirtualHost *
  <VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "D:\XAMPP"
    ServerName localhost
  </VirtualHost>
  <VirtualHost *:8088>
    DocumentRoot "D:\XAMPP\debate_service"
    ServerName debate.service
        ServerAlias www.debate.service
  <Directory "D:\XAMPP\debate_service">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "D:\XAMPP\debate_service"
    ServerName your.service
  <Directory "D:\XAMPP\debate_service">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

The problem is whenever I trying to connect the web for example debate.service:8088 or your.service:8088 on others computer it will redirect me to open dns bla bla bla (because the page was not found),

I have try this on its computer server and the virtual host name works perfect but not on others computer (client host)

How can make it work on others computer?

(Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

You must to set in hosts from client to access the server by name

> 192.168.0.100 your.service
>
> 192.168.0.100 debate.service